# How to add tr or any html tag between two tr

Tags: html, html-table

Following is the html that I am using I want to add one tr between first two trs but it is  not working.
I want to add a html tag and include class for first two tr. How can I achieve that? I do not want to include the submit button's tr in it.

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="content-space" class="content-space">
```

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Subscription Plan:
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="PlanNameId" style="width:auto !Important" name="data[][PlanNameId]">
      <option value="4">
        Disable
      </option>
      <option selected="selected" value="2">
        Free
      </option>
      <option value="1">
        Bronze
      </option>
    </select>

  </td>
  <td>
    &nbsp;
  </td>

</tr>


<tr>
  <td>
    Auto Upgrade:
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="SubscriptionSetting" name="data[][SubscriptionSetting]">
      <option value="1">
        Yes
      </option>
      <option selected="selected" value="0">
        No
      </option>
    </select>

  </td>
  <td>
    &nbsp;
  </td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="signin-button-containers">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="subscriptionsubmit" class="primaryLargeButton">

  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your question is missing the code you said you included. Edit your post and start every row in your code segment with 4 spaces (or more) for StackOverflow to recognize it as code.

Comment: *how to add tr **or any html tag** between two tr* - the only thing that is valid between two `tr` tags **is** a `tr` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the first `tr` and then insert the new row right after it. With jQuery this is very easy, but without any libraries it can also be done without too much effort.

```
$("table tr").first().after("<tr><td>Inserted data</td><td>More data in between</td></tr>")
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qnu3c0uk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 2</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

And that you want to insert a table row (with a cell) after the first table row i would do:

```
$("table tr:first-of-type").after($("<tr>").append("<td>"));
```

If you then want to add a class to the first and the new row, i would do:

```
$("table tr:eq(0),table tr:eq(1)").addClass("row-class");
```

Or actually combining the two parts to:

```
var $newRow = $("<tr>").addClass("new-class");
var $firstRow = $("table tr:first-of-type").addClass("new-class");
$firstRow.after($newRow.append("<td>"));
```